# How to route everything to a specific action except About

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want every link like:

mysite.com/England/English

mysite.com/France/French

mysite.com/Canada/French

To open in this action:

```
public ActionResult Country(string country, string language)
```

but if it's the About:

mysite.com/About

should go to:

```
public ActionResult About()
```

everything else should go to homepage

```
public ActionResult Index()
```

I've tried doing like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "NewRoute",
        "{id}",
        new {controller = "Home", action = "Country", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );

routes.MapRoute(
        "AboutRoute",
        "About",
        New {controller = "Home", action = "About", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

Comment: why cant you make url like this: site.com/country/Countryname/language/     ? where "country" indicates to your controller

Comment: I can. But the site is really small, it will only display a message for each country/language. So trying to reduce the url for an easy memorization.

Comment: then what do you mean by everything else?

Comment: Like mysite.com/one/two/three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put more specific routes at the top. Add catch all route at the end. Try

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        "AboutRoute",
        "About",
        New {controller = "Home", action = "About"}
        );

   routes.MapRoute(
        "NewRoute",
        "{country}/{language}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Country" }
        );

   routes.MapRoute(
        "CatchAll",
        "{*path}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Comment: what about "everything else should go to the index()" ?

Comment: I think it's work. (Edit and delete the unecessary comma in second route definition)